#  Using cross apply in update statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update, cross-apply

Is it possible to use the cross apply clause in the from part of an update statement, in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You where right, Albert. I made some tests and found that it's possible, indeed. The use is the same as in a `SELECT` statement. For example:

```
UPDATE 
    st
SET 
    some_row = A.another_row,
    some_row2 = A.another_row/2
FROM 
    some_table st
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 another_row FROM another_table at WHERE at.shared_id=st.shared_id) AS A
WHERE ...
```

Comment: The above query gave me the error "Incorrect syntax near ')'."  It took me a little while to figure out why so I just want to add the solution here in case anyone runs into it.  Adding an "as" after the cross apply select statement seemed to fix it.

Comment: In SQL Server, I had to replace "UPDATE some_table" with "UPDATE st"

Comment: One benefit of using cross apply is that you can use "top" and "sort"; that enables you to perform the update in a specific order you want.

Comment: I didn't find the need for the alias.  UPDATE some_table Set ... FROM some_table CROSS APPLY WHERE ...